# Django template error while rendering a unicode string

Tags: python, django, unicode

I am passing a python list to a django template like this:

in `views.py`:

```
dat = [-77.448599999999999, 37.536900000000003, u'Virginia War Memorial', 1.0]
result={"dat":dat}
return render(request,'result_map.html', {'form': form,'result':result})
```

and in my template:

```
var dat = {{ result.dat }}
```

but in the rendered html I get:

```
var dat = [-77.448599999999999, 37.536900000000003, u&#39;Virginia War Memorial&#39;, 1.0]
```

which gives an error.

How can I get:

```
var dat = [-77.448599999999999, 37.536900000000003, 'Virginia War Memorial', 1.0]
```

thanks

Comment: Are you seeing this output in a browser?

Comment: nope. the script just quits. I print the html after I render it

Comment: If you render the whole list like that, it will output the __str__ of the list. If you want proper output for each element, you should probably access them directly: '{{ result.dat.2 }}'

Comment: Assuming that you are bothered by the extraneous `u`. The `&#39;` will be properly displayed as `'` by a browser.

Comment: You're first answer was correct and very helpful. I suggest you write it as a real answer. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to pass it through the `safe` filter if you want the raw string:
`{{ result.dat|safe }}`

You can also use the `{% autoescape off %}` block if you want to affect a larger block of the template.

Answer (score 0):

```
var dat = {{ result.dat }}
```

You're trying to inject into JavaScript, presumably in a `<script>` block. You need output that is formatted in JavaScript syntax, but you're implicitly converting a Python list to a string, which will give a Python-syntax list literal, not a JavaScript one. There are a number of differences, including text (Unicode) strings in the list being prefixed with `u` in Python 2 but not JS.

You're also using the default autoescaping for Django templates, which is HTML-escaping. That would be right for injecting into HTML content, but you're injecting into JavaScript, so you get wrong escapes like `&#39;` for `'`. You can prevent this by adding the `|safe` filter to avoid the HTML-escaping, but then you have no escaping at all, so your page will be vulnerable to script injection (cross-site scripting).

The right way to output a structured value into a `<script>` block is:

- `json.dumps` to turn it into a JSON string
- replace any instances of the character `<` in the string with the JSON string literal escape `\u003C`, so that the string `</script>` can't be used to escape from the `<script>` block and inject HTML
- mark as safe.

You can combine these operations into a custom filter. Unfortunately Django itself [doesn't ship one](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/17419).

A better approach is to avoid injecting into JavaScript at all. Instead write the `json.dumps` output into the HTML document using the standard escaping and read it from there using DOM:

```
return render(request, 'result_map.html', {'form': form, 'dat': json.dumps(dat)})
...
<body data-dat="{{ dat }}">
...
var dat= JSON.parse(document.body.getAttribute('data-dat'));
```

this allows you to keep your JS completely out of your HTML pages, which would also allow you to use more secure `Content-Security-Policy` settings.